# Customize new itemize environment

Tags: beamer, environments, itemize, renewcommand

I work with the beamer template Heverlee that has the following setting for the itemize-command:

```
\definecolor{pblue} {RGB}{49,130,189} %primary blue

\setbeamercolor{item} {fg=pblue}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
```

Here is a sample using the code above:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{pblue} {RGB}{49,130,189} %primary blue

\setbeamercolor{item} {fg=pblue}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Sample frame title}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item a
            \item b
            \item c
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

And to have a second itemize, I want exactly the same just with another name and another color, I tried the following:

```
\newenvironment{myitemize}

{\itemize\let\origitem\item[1][triangle]

\renewcommand{\item}{fg=pgreen}}

{\enditemize}
```

But I get the error message that an \item might be missing if I want to use it with \begin{myitemize}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could read this question and [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360424/changing-the-color-of-bullets-in-new-defined-blocks-in-beamer?rq=1) which could be applied to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way the `itemize` environment behaves (like spacing or in our case we want to change its `label` or "bullet points").

We have to use the `enumitem` package to be able to change the environment and create new environments similar to `itemize`.

We also use the `xcolor` package to define colors.

The symbol we want to use is `\blacktriangleright` and can only be created using math mode (put in `$` symbols around the command) as following.

Change existing `itemize` environment:

```
\setlist[itemize]{
    label={$\blacktriangleright$}
}
```

Create a new itemize environment and let's call it itemize2:

```
\newlist{itemize2}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[itemize2,1]{
    label={$\blacktriangleright$}
}
```

defining a color works as follows:

```
\definecolor{pblue}{RGB}{49,130,189}
```

The following code gets pretty close to what you want to do I think. First let's do it in the document class `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\definecolor{pblue}{RGB}{49,130,189}

\setlist[itemize]{
    label={\textcolor{pblue}{$\blacktriangleright$}}
}

\definecolor{pgreen}{RGB}{49,189,130}

\newlist{itemize2}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[itemize2,1]{
    label={\textcolor{pgreen}{$\blacktriangleright$}}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item a
            \item b
            \item c
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize2}
            \item a
            \item b
            \item c
        \end{itemize2}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Now how about doing the same in a different document class?:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\definecolor{pblue}{RGB}{49,130,189}

\setlist[itemize]{
    label={\textcolor{pblue}{$\blacktriangleright$}}
}

\definecolor{pgreen}{RGB}{49,189,130}

\newlist{itemize2}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[itemize2,1]{
    label={\textcolor{pgreen}{$\blacktriangleright$}}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
    \end{itemize}
    
    \begin{itemize2}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
    \end{itemize2}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `enumitem` package doesn’t really work with `Beamer`.

Comment: You are right! Apparently it seems to not be the ideal solution. More can be read here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31524/206040 - consider this being a "hacky" solution for the `beamer` class. For other document classes this should be fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to combine the idea in the link posted by John and the template itself:

```
    \newenvironment<>{try1}[1]{%
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=pgreen}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white!95!green}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=white!95!pgreen}%
  \begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}
```

I just created a new block environment and set the conditions for itemize within this environment.